# Java LDAP bind response takes too long

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ldap, bind

I have an application that uses LDAP and communicates in a server client way using Sun's jndi library. The problem is that when many connections are trying to be established at once I see a lot of failed connections because bind response is not sent in desired time interval. 
Is there a way to enhance this?
It is not unusual that there are >200 connections at once. Everything works OK until ~60 connections and after that it becomes too slow.

P.S.There is no possibility to increase waiting time.

Every connection is running in a separate thread like this:

```
    ...
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    infinite loop:
    newSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    newSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    Thread t = new Thread(/*runnable that does something*/);
    t.start();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Will it be possible to use a connection pool ?

Comment: You state that there is no possibility to increase waiting time.  What kind of response time are you expecting?  Are you reaching any limits on your LDAP server side that might account for the slowdown?  And the obvious, why are you opening so many connections in such a short period of time with authentications?  Are you attempting to stress test the LDAP service?

Comment: I need to mention that inconvenient circumstance is that all connections need to be established at once. If I put a delay server will consider them dead and retry. @Nizzo unfortunately it is not a stress test but a prerequisition for other parts of the system that utilize this data. Right now that is not a problem, only the connecting part is troubling. Expected response time shouldn't be higher than 700ms. I haven't tried a connection pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to share with you that I set a higher value for backlog and also I cleaned up run method a lot, making the transfer part the first thing that executes and then doing the analysis. Thanks four your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have networking code in the constructor of the Runnable. Move it to the `run()` method so that it runs in its own thread instead of the thread that is calling `accept().`

Comment: My networking code is in the run method, it uses a try-catch-finally where it opens buffered streams, analyzes/sends the message and closes resources. And thread that is calling accept() has mostly this what I wrote above. I also tried various values of newsocket.setPerformancePreferences() but it didn't help.

Comment: @HrvojeG. If what you say is true there is nothing that can hold up the `accept()` thread. If your `accept()` thread is being held up, what you say cannot be true. If your `accept()` thread isn't being held up I suggest you post the code that *is* being held up. At present your question doesn't make sense.